# Find only one subset sum with a specified value

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, subset-sum

Not printing all subsets with a specified sum, but only one and with the smallest time complexity.

```
found = False


def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    global found
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target:
        found = True
        print("sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target))
    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    if found:
        return

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])
```

The problem is that is too slow for large data (10000 elements).

Comment: Can you please add some code you tried out and what issue did you encountered?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with what you have? Do you have a test case that demonstrates this failure?

Comment: Thank you for the question, @martineau . I edited my question.

Comment: You need a test case that gives the wrong answer. You could provide a clearer statement on what the function does. However, if it's working correctly, except you want to improve performance, consider codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you are concerned that it keeps returning results after you set found=true, that's because there's no return path to shortcircuit. Just a loop. You could raise a custom exception to get all the way out to a try-except block.

Comment: The title, and the first line (_Not printing all subsets with a specified sum, but only one and with the smallest time complexity._), seem to indicate that the issue is your not producing the correct response. The last sentence of your post, however, says something entirely different: _The problem is that is too slow for large data (10000 elements)._ Which is it? Also, please share a [mcve].

Comment: subset_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 6) prints multiple matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive functions are troublesome in real-world applications, since each instance of the method call needs to be tracked by the interpreter. If possible, write your function in a loop, rather than calling it recursively.

Here's an algorithm which repeatedly tries to add the largest value in the input lower than the remaining value. If it fails, it removes the largest value tried and starts from the beginning. It will return the first solution it finds. Takes about 8 seconds in a set of 10,000 values.

```
def one_subset_sum(sum_val: int, set_ints: list):
  test_subset = []
  filtered_ints = list(filter(lambda x:x<=sum_val,set_ints))
  while sum(test_subset) < sum_val and len(set_ints) > 0:
    remainder = sum_val - sum(test_subset)
    filtered_ints = list(filter(lambda x:x<=remainder,filtered_ints))
    if len(filtered_ints) == 0:
        set_ints.remove(max(set_ints))
        test_subset = []
        filtered_ints = list(filter(lambda x:x<=sum_val,set_ints))
        if sum(set_ints) < sum_val:
            return []
        continue
    test_subset.append(max(filtered_ints))
    filtered_ints.remove(test_subset[-1])
  return test_subset
```

Comment: Thank you! This matched my needs. 